# Drawing tiles on canvas has blurry gaps

Tags: javascript, canvas

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/jm1y9c0L/1/

Code:

```
const context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
const scale = document.getElementById("scale");
const translate = document.getElementById("translate");
scale.value = 17.78598548284369;
translate.value = 10.02842190048295;
function draw() {
    context.fillStyle="#f00";
    context.fillRect(0,0,1,1);
    context.fillRect(1,0,1,1);
}
function update() {
    const s = Number(scale.value);
    const t = Number(translate.value);
    context.clearRect(0,0,100,100);
    context.save();
    context.translate(t,t);
    context.scale(s,s);
    draw();
    context.restore();
}
update();
```

Question: How do I draw tiles on canvas in a scaled context on canvas without blurry gaps?

A few things to note:
If I don't change the background to black, things look ok:
https://jsfiddle.net/jm1y9c0L/2/

I think if I draw all tiles on a buffer and draw the buffer on the canvas scaled, it would work. But that has many issues, one being it potentially uses a lot of memory if I'm scaling a very large buffer smaller.

Edit:
To explain my goal better, I want to draw two rectangles next to each other with its boundaries being a fraction. So if I draw two rectangles, one in green and one in red with a black background. I want to see the boundary being half green, half red, but not black at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using floats and not integers, canvas cant draw 0.78598548284369 of a pixel, I would recommend putting Math.floor() around your scale in the scale() function:

`context.scale(Math.floor(s),Math.floor(s));`

Hope this helps :D

Comment: Thanks for replying. But this is not what I want, I edited the post to explain my goal better.

Comment: Even with the update its not clear to me what you are trying to do, or why the answer above is not sufficient.  https://imgur.com/aST2xgU    This issue of non-perfect-looking boundaries when using vector graphics & fractional pixel sizes or coordinates is not limited to HTML canvas, subpixel alignment is something that virtually all graphic design applications have to deal with.  If I understand your concern correctly then im afraid its just a limitation of the medium.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do subpixel rendering in a browser (at least you can't expect consistent results). In your case, the end of one rectangle isn't necesarily the start of the other, since there may or may not be a pixel-wide gap which comes from rounding.

You might even notice some weird behaviour, such as getting different results in different screen positions, different browsers, when resizing, etc.

The solution is to calculate the value of each pixel yourself, not let the browser do it for you.